# Woocommerce products not in local database but from live API

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Would it be possible to not have the Woocommerce products in the local datbase but load them from an API?

My supplier only has an API, I cannot download or import a database, every product / product list / categorie etc has to be requested from the API. 
Ofcourse I can do some caching,  but the question is :

**Can Woocommerce handle products that are not in the local database but come  from a live API**

== EDIT ==
I have to pay for this API per Gb.  So I can not fetch all data, this would cost 1000ths of dollars per month. Speed is not an issue,  there are hundreds of shops connected to this live API and thes shop work fine.  I agree,  all products in the local database would be better,  but ....

Answer (score 0):

There is no default functionality like what you are looking for. It would be impossible for the developers of Woocommerce to be able to predict every possible API connection. The implementation of such a scenario would be non-trivial. You would have to hook into so many parts of Woocommerce in order to make it work. It could be done (there are hooks all through the code base), but it would be a tremendous task. However, before you decide to take it on anyway, understand that doing so would make your site unbearably slow. Woocommerce isn't very fast to begin with, but making live API calls (possibly multiple calls) for every page view would be a terrible UX for your visitors.

Instead, write a plugin that uses wp-cron to call the API and fill the Woocommerce tables periodically as a background process. This should allow you to have all the information from the vendor cached locally (what if they were ever down?) and the speed would be considerably better. Also you wouldn't have to change anything in Woocommerce.

Answer (score 0):

As BA_Webimax replied and it is so true there is no default functionalit exist in woocommerce to fetch product from API / live database.

I had implemented funcionality in which product,image,price everything stream from different API and in which i implemented functionality to fetch all data from API online and display product shop page and single product page runtime from API.

But when user add product into cart at that time add individual product with it's image/detail/price as woocommerce product into woocommerce database.so after adding product into woocommerce you can use all default functionalities of woocommerce during checkout,discount,shipping,coupen,payment and placing of order which would manage by woocommerce itself.

Comment: Thanks Ash,  can you explain this a bit further?  Do you have example code?